# Aginity Workbench Redshift Server Connection Error

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

I've downloaded Aginity Workbench for Redshift, version 4.3.

I'm receiving the error message

```
The Connection is not open
```

I selected my server endpoint by using this document: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/gsg/rs-gsg-connect-to-cluster.html

example from link: examplecluster.userid.us-west-2.redshift.amazonaws.com

Port is 5439

I noticed right away that I could select a database from the dropdown.  If I supply the database name I still get the error message "The connection is not open", does anybody know what I'm missing?  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

lowercase loginid  should fix your issue.

Answer (score 0):

This could be several things.

Does the instance require SSL connections? If so, select 'require' for the SSL mode in the connection setup.

Also, the link doesn't typically contain a 'userid' (examplecluster.userid.us-west-2.redshift.amazonaws.com). You can get the endpoint from the configuration tab in AWS management console for the redshift instance. The page looks just like the image referenced in the doc here. 
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/gsg/rs-gsg-connect-to-cluster.html

Comment: AFHood,  I went to the console page and copied the endpoint exactly.  I tried all the settings for the SSL box (ie Allow, Require, disable, etc.) and I still couldn't retrieve a database or connect.  Any other ideas?

Comment: I would also check the security groups on the redshift cluster to make sure you aren't blocking your connection.

Answer (score 0):

`The Connection is not open` is the error at beginning stage, so could you please check if there are any firewall issue. run the command from your computer:

```
telnet examplecluster.userid.us-west-2.redshift.amazonaws.com 5439
```

If can't, you need check the security group setting on that redshift cluster instance and open inbound port 5439 to public or your own IP address.